# Restricting pipes and redirects (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a program that takes standard input from the user and runs through the command line. Is there someway to make a program ignore pipes and redirects?

For example: `python program.py < input.txt > output.txt` would just act as if you put in `python program.py`

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to find the terminal the user launched you with in the general case.  There are some techniques you can use, but they will not always work.

You can use [`os.isatty()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.isatty) to detect whether a file (such as `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout`) appears to be an interactive terminal session.  It is possible you are hooked up to a terminal session other than the one the user used to launch your program, so this is not foolproof.  Such a terminal session might even be under the control of a program rather than a human.

Under Unix, processes have a notion of a "controlling terminal."  You may be able to talk to that via [`os.ctermid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.ctermid).  But the user can manipulate this value before launching your process.  You also may not have a controlling terminal at all, e.g. if running as a daemon.

You can inspect the parent process and see if any of its file descriptors are hooked up to terminal sessions.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any cross-platform way to do that.  On Linux, I'd start with [`os.getppid()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getppid) and the `/proc` filesystem (see [`proc(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)).  If the parent process has exited (e.g. the user ran `your_program.py & disown; exit` under bash), this will not work.  But in that case, there isn't much you can do anyway.